# Listen to play/next/previous hotkeys on Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, hotkeys

I'm using [OsSupport-Connector](https://bitbucket.org/agynamix/ossupport-connector) to make my Java application listen to some global hotkeys. However, I couldn't find the code that is associated with the play/next/previous keys, which are present in every MacBook keyboard.

How can I listen to these particular hotkeys?

Thanks

Comment: do you know there numeric value?

Comment: @elyashiv No, I have no ideia... How can I find it out?

Comment: try (in c): `char a = getch(); cout << (int)a;`

Comment: @elyashiv I don't have the tools to program in c on my mac, but I need `int modifier, long modifierFlags, int keycode` for the library I'm using

Comment: I have also the exact same problem. However I am even more behind you. I don't even know how to use the OSSupport-Connector. I've noticed that there are 3 jars in the Downloads section of the project. Which ones do I need to add to my project? (I need 64bit support BTW) And then, how to exactly use it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will find [this project](https://bitbucket.org/thebitguru/whitedragon) useful. Its not exactly what you looking for but if you look deeper into it you might find your solution.

Comment: I took a look at the project you suggested. But the author uses:
`#define NX_KEYTYPE_PLAY     16
#define NX_KEYTYPE_NEXT     17
#define NX_KEYTYPE_PREVIOUS   18`

And with OsSupport-Connector I need:
`int modifier, long modifierFlags, int keycode`

Any idea how these are related?